# How does my HTML file interact with my Python program?

Tags: python, html, python-3.x

I have a html file that needs to display a random message every time you refresh the page. I am thinking of using a python program that will generate the random message. But how do I get the message from my python program into my html file? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using flask, example app.py

```
from flask import Flask, render_template


app = Flask(__name__)

random_message = "some random message"


@app.route("/")
def main():
    return render_template(["index.html"], value=random_message)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

create a directory templates and put in the index.html file with content

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    {{ value }}

    </body>
</html>
```

You can read about flask here http://flask.pocoo.org/

Answer (score 0):

Use flask it will render you message to to HTML file its is a Python micro framework